# Graphics not being displayed on OUYA

Tags: java, android, libgdx, ouya

I hope its not too early to be asking OUYA dev questions, but I just got my dev kit and I want to get my game running ASAP! I am using LibGDX as my framework for my game and launching the Android backend on the OUYA. Everything seems fine except that none of my graphics are being displayed! I can only tell what's going on because of Box2D's DebugDraw showing my physics. I am using LibGdx's Spritebatch and OpenGL ES 2.0. Everything is working pefectly on my desktop and Android (phone) backends.

Am I doing something wrong with handling my resources for OUYA? What could be the problem? Could this be because I store my graphics in the assets folder instead of /res?

Edit: Here's a logcat output: http://pastebin.com/BbPyPCcR

Comment: A simple check of your images will easily prove/dis-prove your theory. That is assuming if an image can't be found something gets returned to show the error..

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to do that. I'm using Libgdx and there are no errors, everything is running smoothly.

Comment: I have just updated to LibGDX v0.9.7 to no avail. I assumed that some updated libraries/drivers would do the trick, but no dice.

Comment: Sweet, you have an OUYA console! +1

Comment: I don't think many people have experience with OUYA. Perhaps it's better if you ask on their forums and paste the answer your self?

Comment: @Sidar, I have been posting on their forums (http://bit.ly/XFVpnP) and even emailed their dev support team to no avail. The only suggestion I've heard is create a test app with Libgdx and go from there. However, I have seen others getting libgdx to work, so I don't understand why mine won't.

Comment: I don't think it's libgdx though. But yeah you could try and see if a clean project displaying one sprite in the center works though.

Comment: You can also post this question on the OUYA Forums if you'd like :) It may receive more attention there as there aren't many OUYA questions on any SE site at the moment

Comment: I'm kind of stumped with your statement of 'Everything works...'. Do you mean the application runs without an error and you see nothing on your desktop AND android? When you say Android backend, do you mean the simulator?

Comment: Libgdx is crossplatform. There is a backend for each platform. The application works on all platforms (including Android devices) without errors except OUYA (with the Android backend being used since OUYA is Android). The only thing wrong on the OUYA is my textures are invisible or black (can't tell). The whole screen is black except the Box2D DebugDraw which is how I know the app is still working. There are no errors except the couple in the logcat I posted.

Comment: So no, @ViteFalcon, I do not mean the emulator.

Comment: @Amplify91, are you using any shaders in your game?

Comment: @Amplify91 What Android phone are you using? Because the OUYA is built on a Tegra 3, and your phone could be running a different GPU.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about ouya but seeing the log,

```
01-02 07:09:21.490: W/PackageManager(305): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-02 07:09:21.490: W/PackageManager(305):      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.putCachedIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:782)

01-02 07:09:21.490: W/PackageManager(305):      at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:618)

01-02 07:09:21.490: W/PackageManager(305):      at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
```

Suggests a wrong location of images. Recheck that the url is not null.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the image is where it should be? maybe that's why the desktop project works and ouya's doesn't

also how come it gives you an exception but you can still see things on the box2d debug?
what happens if you disable the drawing of box2d debug?

gl if your doing the jam and I hope you'll solve this fast